# openERP res.partners add custom field, but not result

Tags: python, odoo

i added field to res.partner

```
    <record id="mypartner_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">partner.myform</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <field name="name" position="after">
                <field name="partner_category_id" />
           </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

but not result

```
from openerp.osv import fields,osv,orm
_inherit = "res.partner"
_columns = {

    'partner_category_id':fields.many2one('partner.category','Partner Category'),
}
```

please help

i want  to add filed after Customer and Suppliers and  there is no result

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
from openerp.osv import fields,osv,orm

class res_partner_extension(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "res.partner"
    _columns = {
            'partner_category_id':fields.many2one('partner.category','Partner    Category'),
}
```

Comment: not works :( i  in form i wrote model res.partner,should i write inherit in form 
res.partner.extension ?

Comment: What error are you facing? Did you checked the module dependency? Did you restarted the server and updated the module? Check at the database side whether your column is created or not? Did you add your `.py` file in `__init__.py` file?

Comment: i used <data> tag  before declaring python  variable and it's works, thanks